# Using ModelSerializer for existence validation

Tags: django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a model with a foreign key and want to use that related model's serializer for serializing the data, but use it for existence check on create/update.

```
class SongSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  artist = ArtistSerializer()
  name = serializers.CharField()
```

This serializer works perfectly for the serialization, but for create or update it tries to create the `Artist`.

What I want to happen is that rather than validate the data as a new instance, I can suppress its validation, so that I can run my own validation in which I use the artist data to verify that the specified exists:

```
def validate_artist(self, artist):
  # ignore the lack of error checking
  id = artist.get('id')
  artist = Artist.objects.filter(id=id).first()
  if not artist:
    raise ValidationError("Specified Artist not found")
  return artist
```

I tried providing `validators` to `ArtistSerializer` but it still runs its own validation first. If I set it to `read_only=True`, `validate_artist()` won't get called. While I can get it from `initial_data` in `validate()`, I was hoping there was a less hacky way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The built-in fields don't work this way, but you can can do it with 2 serializers and a selector based on the `action`.

```py
class SongListItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    artist = ArtistSerializer()
    ....
    
class SongCreateSerializer(SongListSerializer):
    artist = PrimaryKeyRelatedField(...)
    ...
```

In your view just select the correct serializer:

```
def get_serializer_class(self):
    if self.action == "create":
        return SongCreateSerializer
    else:
        return SongListItemSerializer
```

You can also write a custom field that would work this way, but that is quite a task and would also mess with schema generation.  I wish this was a standard feature of DRF too, so we use a custom base class which implements this with a bit more advanced logic (e.g. if you ask for "detail" but it's not there, then use the "list" one).