DRF - Creating new object on POST with reference to existing object
(I am new to Django Rest Framework and Django in general)
I have a Beer model that looks like this:
class Beer(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    brewery = models.ForeignKey(Brewery, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    beer_type = models.ForeignKey(BeerType, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "beer"

I then specify a BeerSerializer like this:
class BeerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    brewery = BrewerySerializer()
    beer_type = BeerTypeSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Beer
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'brewery', 'beer_type']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        brewery_data = validated_data.pop('brewery')
        beer_type_data = validated_data.pop('beer_type')
        beer = Beer.objects.create(**validated_data)
        beer.brewery = Brewery.objects.get_or_create(**brewery_data)
        beer.beer_type = BeerType.objects.get_or_create(**beer_type_data)
        return beer

And a BeerViewSet:
class BeerViewSet(viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
    serializer_class = BeerSerializer

...
    def create(self, request):
        pdb.set_trace()
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

(I've left out the list and retrieve implementations in the ViewSet)
When I then make a POST request from my app to /api/beers/ with the following JSON:
{
    "beer_type": {
        "id": 154,
        "name": "Beer Type 1"
    },
    "brewery": {
        "country": "c1",
        "id": 929,
        "location": "l1",
        "name": "Brewery1"
    },
    "name": "Beer1"
}

I get an error with code 400 and error body:
{
    "beer_type": {
        "name": [
            "beer type with this name already exists."
        ]
    }
}

This is technically true, but what am I doing wrong if I want to allow a POST creating a new Beer object, which references an existing BeerType object (and I guess I would have the same problem with the Brewery reference)?
Update:
I thought I'd just share my serializers for by Beer class, based on the accepted answer below:
class BeerSerializerGet(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    brewery = BrewerySerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Beer
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'brewery', 'beer_type']
        depth = 1
        validators = []


class BeerSerializerCreate(BeerSerializerGet):
    brewery = PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Brewery.objects)

And then my ViewSet sets the correct serializers, as well as finding the existing brewery and beerType based on the received IDs:
class BeerViewSet(viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]

    def list(self, request):
        queryset = Beer.objects.all()
        serializer_context = {'request': request}
        serializer = BeerSerializerGet(queryset, many=True, context=serializer_context)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def retrieve(self, request, pk=None):
        queryset = Beer.objects.all()
        beer = get_object_or_404(queryset, pk=pk)
        serializer_context = {'request': request}
        serializer = BeerSerializerGet(beer, context=serializer_context)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def create(self, request):
        beerName = request.data['name']
        pdb.set_trace()
        breweryId = request.data['brewery_id']
        beerTypeId = request.data['beer_type_id']
        brewery = get_object_or_404(Brewery.objects.all(), pk=breweryId)
        beerType = get_object_or_404(BeerType.objects.all(), pk=beerTypeId)
        beer = Beer.objects.create(name = beerName, brewery=brewery, beer_type=beerType)
        serializer_context = {'request': request}
        serializer = BeerSerializerGet(beer, context=serializer_context)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

UPDATE 2:
I just realised that the above doesn't use the two different serialisers, but actually only uses the GET one, and the ViewSet handles getting the correct brewery/beerType and passing them in... is this bad practice, or is that also a valid solution?

I think a package makes this trivial, but without the package there’s some boilerplate https://github.com/beda-software/drf-writable-nested

Boilerplate as in custom validator for beer_type

Thank you @AdamJenkins. These both sound like good options. I might try going the boilerplate/custom validator route first, as that might be a better way for me to learn :)

You aren't trying to create a new nested object, that's good.  A reliable and clear way to do what you want is with different serializers for 'create/update' and 'list'.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78050502/using-modelserializer-for-existence-validation/78056717#78056717

Thank you @Andrew, but I'm not quite understanding the parallel from that Answer. In that case to OP wants to sometimes Create and sometimes Update. But in my case I want to Create a Beer object but just retrieve the BeerType and Brewery... So it seems to me that I somehow have to change the BeerSerializer to not create the BeerType and Brewery, even when it is creating the Beer...

Sorry, maybe I'm just not quite understanding the answer. The question does indeed sound like the same situation...

Are you referring to yourself as "OP"?  From what I see you want to read in one format (with expanded children) and when you "create" a record you want to supply the ID of the existing related record.  There are only 2 ways to do that - 2 different serializers, or a custom field which does the conversion.  Nested creation doesn't exist in the framework, it's always custom code.

@Andrew Sorry, I meant the OP of the question you linked to. I realise now that wasn't very clear :P
OK, thank you! I'll have another go at using two different serializers next time I have time to work on the project :)

Sorry about the comment, I somehow missed the nested writing.  This is not necessarily an answer, just my thoughts.
It is much lest complicated to just not support nested writes.  It is possible, https://github.com/beda-software/drf-writable-nested will help, but I think you'll get unexpected updates and it's a bad precedent to set in general.
When they are needed, for us, I use a serializer like yours and manually process everything.  Multiple items could have the same child, and the first will succeed while the 2nd would fail, so I manually de-dupe, etc.  It's a custom "import" endpoint at that point.
A multi-serializer solution:
I favor using a different serializer for each "action", which can behave differently.  Then you can get the "rich" output view with a "lean" create/update view, as well as control exactly what is visible where, and alter behavior in specific use cases.
Start off with a create serializer which uses the default behavior.  This will accept an ID for the brewery, so {"brewery": 1}
class BeerEditSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Beer
        fields = "__all__"

Create a 2nd serializer for the list action.  You can inherit from the previous one if you want, but I find it safer to keep them independent.
class BeerViewSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    brewery = BrewerySerializer()
    beer_type = BeerTypeSerializer()

    class Meta:
        ....

In your view you can now return the correct value based on the viewset action being used for the request:
class 
    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.action in ["list", "retrieve"]:
            return BeerViewSerializer
        else:
            return BeerEditSerializer

I like to create a read only serializer to prevent accidentally using the wrong one, and have some viewset mixins to automate the above logic.
class ReadOnlyModelSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    def update(self, *args, **kwargs):
        raise NotImplementedError("Editing is not supported")
    def create(self, *args, **kwargs):
        raise NotImplementedError("Editing is not supported")
    

Using ModelViewset is fine too, but you should copy the base implementation and remove mixins you don't want to work, such as DestroyModelMixin

I finally got time to look at this again, and it seems like I actually got it working last time (but only at the very end so didn't even realise :P). I had to make changes to my client as it now gets the brewery in a beer expanded, but when it creates a new beer it has to just include the brewery_id, etc, but I can get around that with some JsonAdapters and SerializedName annotations :D Thank you!

Oh! I actually didn't do it with two serializers, I just realise, but instead just with one and just create the beer object in the viewset and pass that into the serialiser... is that bad?

It's not bad - it's code and it works!  In my opinion it's brittle (unexpected updates, complicated logic) and unexpected - and you need a regular endpoint anyway to work with the individual breweries.  Just keep using it and see if you run into issues, and if it works for you then

Thank you! I'll see how it goes. For now it's just a great relief to have something working, but it would be a good learning experience to try to get it working the other way as well, if I get the time :) Thank you for your help!
